# Evaluate $\int_1^4 \frac{1}{(4x-1)\sqrt{x}} \,\rm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $\int_1^4 \frac{1}{(4x-1)\sqrt{x}} \,\rm{d}x$

Now, my attempt was substitute $\sqrt{x}=u \rightarrow \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ dx=du
With the new bounds  u=1 , u=2

Then, $\int_1^2 2\frac{1}{(4u^2-1)} \,\rm{d}u$

The problem that i have is with partial fractions, can someone show me the correct way to apply partial fractions here ? (With the undetermined coefficients method )

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Difference of two squares

Comment: \begin{align}4u^4-1&=(2u^2+1)(2u^2-1)\\&=(2u^2+1)(\sqrt{2}u+1)(\sqrt{2}u-1)\\\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you meant the denominator to be $4u^2-1$, not $4u^4-1$. Since $4u^2-1=(2u-1)(2u+1)$, we need to find $A,\,B$ such that $\frac{2}{4u^2-1}=\frac{A}{2u-1}+\frac{B}{2u+1}$.

Multiplying by $4u^2-1$, $2=A(2u+1)+B(2u-1)=(2A+2B)u+A-B$, so $2A+2B=0,\,A-B=2$. I'll leave solving for $A,\,B$ & the integration to you.

For what it's worth, $y=2u$ makes it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can Decompose it as :
$\frac a {2u -1} + \frac b {2u +1} $
such that :

$a(2u +1) + b(2u -1) = 2$

Therefore a = 1/2 and b = -1/2
integrating them will give :

$ \frac {ln(2u - 1)} 2 - \frac {ln(2u+1)} 2 + c$